# Why I can't get multiple data from MongoDB? Where I can insert on the same collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, server

I am using express server with MongoDB. Here in a collection called "request" I am able to use the **insertOne**, **findOne**, but I when I try to use **find** oparator it's getting some weird result. I have found the same question on MongoDB's dev-community but got no answer from there.
How can I resolve this, expecting help.

Thanks in advance :)

> Client Side

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/getRequests", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        email: email,
        type: type,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setRequests(data);
      });
  }, [user, type]);
```

> Server Side

```
exports.getRequests = async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.headers?.email;
  const type = req.headers?.type;
  let filter;
  if (type === "incoming") {
    filter = { to: email };
  } else {
    filter = { from: email };
  }
  const requestsResult = await requestCollection.find(filter);
  console.log(requestsResult);
  res.send(requestsResult);
};
```

> What I am getting as result

```
<ref *2> FindCursor {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(client)]: <ref *1> MongoClient {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    s: {
      url: 'mongodb+srv://shohoj-pay:gNhIoU7Xp521361w@cluster0.0lpuf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
      bsonOptions: [Object],
      namespace: [MongoDBNamespace],
      hasBeenClosed: false,
      sessionPool: [ServerSessionPool],
      activeSessions: [Set],
      options: [Getter],
      readConcern: [Getter],
      writeConcern: [Getter],
      readPreference: [Getter],
      logger: [Getter],
      isMongoClient: [Getter]
    },
    topology: Topology {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 25,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      bson: [Object: null prototype],
      s: [Object],
      client: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(waitQueue)]: [Denque]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      hosts: [Array],
      credentials: [MongoCredentials],
      serverApi: [Object],
      compressors: [Array],
      connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
      directConnection: false,
      metadata: [Object],
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      keepAlive: true,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 120000,
      loadBalanced: false,
      localThresholdMS: 15,
      logger: [Logger],
      maxConnecting: 2,
      maxIdleTimeMS: 0,
      maxPoolSize: 100,
      minPoolSize: 0,
      minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500,
      monitorCommands: false,
      noDelay: true,
      pkFactory: [Object],
      raw: false,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      retryReads: true,
      retryWrites: true,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      srvMaxHosts: 0,
      srvServiceName: 'mongodb',
      writeConcern: [WriteConcern],
      waitQueueTimeoutMS: 0,
      zlibCompressionLevel: 0,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      dbName: 'test',
      userSpecifiedAuthSource: false,
      userSpecifiedReplicaSet: false,
      srvHost: 'cluster0.0lpuf.mongodb.net',
      tls: true,
      replicaSet: 'atlas-141ncy-shard-0'
    }
  },
  [Symbol(namespace)]: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'shohoj-pay', collection: 'request' },
  [Symbol(documents)]: [],
  [Symbol(initialized)]: false,
  [Symbol(closed)]: false,
  [Symbol(killed)]: false,
  [Symbol(options)]: {
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    raw: false,
    enableUtf8Validation: true
  },
  [Symbol(session)]: ClientSession {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { ended: [Function] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    client: <ref *1> MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      topology: [Topology],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    sessionPool: ServerSessionPool { client: [MongoClient], sessions: [] },
    hasEnded: false,
    clientOptions: [Object: null prototype] {
      hosts: [Array],
      credentials: [MongoCredentials],
      serverApi: [Object],
      compressors: [Array],
      connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
      directConnection: false,
      metadata: [Object],
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      keepAlive: true,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 120000,
      loadBalanced: false,
      localThresholdMS: 15,
      logger: [Logger],
      maxConnecting: 2,
      maxIdleTimeMS: 0,
      maxPoolSize: 100,
      minPoolSize: 0,
      minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500,
      monitorCommands: false,
      noDelay: true,
      pkFactory: [Object],
      raw: false,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      retryReads: true,
      retryWrites: true,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      srvMaxHosts: 0,
      srvServiceName: 'mongodb',
      writeConcern: [WriteConcern],
      waitQueueTimeoutMS: 0,
      zlibCompressionLevel: 0,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      dbName: 'test',
      userSpecifiedAuthSource: false,
      userSpecifiedReplicaSet: false,
      srvHost: 'cluster0.0lpuf.mongodb.net',
      tls: true,
      replicaSet: 'atlas-141ncy-shard-0'
    },
    explicit: false,
    supports: { causalConsistency: true },
    clusterTime: undefined,
    operationTime: undefined,
    owner: [Circular *2],
    defaultTransactionOptions: {},
    transaction: Transaction {
      state: 'NO_TRANSACTION',
      options: {},
      _pinnedServer: undefined,
      _recoveryToken: undefined
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(snapshotEnabled)]: false,
    [Symbol(serverSession)]: null,
    [Symbol(txnNumberIncrement)]: 0
  },
  [Symbol(filter)]: { to: 'shahadat2772@gmail.com' },
  [Symbol(builtOptions)]: {
    raw: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    enableUtf8Validation: true,
    writeConcern: WriteConcern { w: 'majority' },
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's weird about this?  The fact that it returned a FindCursor?  Do you know how to [access data from a cursor](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/)?

Comment: I was missing the .toArray(), Thanks a lot